# Terminology: Gauge stress?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, units, continuum-mechanics

When a material is loaded with a force, the stress at some location in the material is
defined as the applied force per unit of cross-sectional area.

If I have a material submerged in pressurized water, I may say that the stress within the material is equal to the pressure of the water.  I measure the pressure of the water with a pressure gauge and find the pressure to be X psig.  Would it be correct to say the stress within the material is equal to X psig?  -- I have always seen stress as having units of psi, without any mention of absolute or gauge measurement.

Absolute pressure is zero-referenced against a perfect vacuum, so it is equal to gauge pressure plus atmospheric pressure.  Units may be psia (pound-force per square inch, absolute).

Gauge pressure is zero-referenced against ambient air pressure, so it is equal to absolute pressure minus atmospheric pressure. Using atmospheric pressure as reference is usually signified by a g for gauge after the pressure unit, e.g. 70 psig, which means that the pressure measured is the total (absolute) pressure minus atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Surely only a pressure *difference* will give rise to a stress? Because the pressure on the submerged object is (presumably) isotropic, the stress is independent of the water pressure. Only if the object is hollow, say, with a different pressure in the cavity than the surrounding water pressure will the material be under stress.

Comment: @tok3rat0r I just know that the term stress is used to express the loading in terms of force applied to a certain cross-sectional area of an object.  I would think the stress within a submerged object in 1 psig water would be different than in 10,000 psig water.  But, my question is more about the units allowed for stress -- can I use psig for stress?

Comment: Well the 'units' are the same whether you use psig or psia; all that matters from a physical perspective is, as you say, the loading applied to a given area. And that depends on the pressure differential between different surfaces. Take your example of 1 psig vs. 10,000 psig water; if a solid block of material is immersed in water at each of these pressure levels, the material is under no more stress in the high-pressure than in the low-pressure case. Only if there is a pressure *difference* across a surface (as in a submarine, for example) is the external pressure relevant.

Comment: In the submarine example, you can see that the only pressures which matter are the water pressure and the pressure inside the submarine (which need not be equal to the air pressure on the surface). The *difference* between these two is what governs the net force per unit area on the skin of the submarine. It has nothing to do with psig or psia of the water, only with psi(water)-psi(sub).

Comment: @tok3rat0r I see what you are saying, it falls in line with my understanding of effective stress.  But, as wiki says, "stress is a physical quantity that expresses the internal forces that neighboring particles of a continuous material exert on each other." Wouldn't the particles of the solid block exert larger forces on their neighbors in the 10,000 psi case compared to the 1 psi case?  Wouldn't the amount of deformation of the solid object at the 10 ksi case vs. the 1 psi case lend it self to this thought?

Comment: Yes, I suppose in that sense (defined on Wikipedia as the [hydrostatic stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_stress), which is just equal to the pressure) the water pressure is relevant. It seems that this is conventionally taken with respect to atmospheric pressure, so psig in this case would be the relevant quantity. It has to be emphasised though that there's nothing 'special' about atmospheric pressure (apart from its convenience to us as a standard gauge); all that matters is that there's a common reference point against which the pressure is measured.

Comment: An important measure here is the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus), which is the inverse of the material's compressibility. All solids and liquids have such a high bulk modulus that for most practical purposes they can be considered incompressible (hence the hydrostatic stress isn't really relevant in these cases). Only gases are sufficiently compressible that we need to account for hydrostatic stress, and then we can define the internal pressure of the gas in order to help us with our calculation (in accordance with the submarine example I gave earlier).